# GWT Cell Callback

Tags: gwt, asynchronous, cell

I am writing a custom cell for GWT, but the data to be displayed will be fetched asynchronously (REST call). How do I make the rendering asynch for the cell?

I see ImageLoadingCell shows a spinner, then shows the image when it is loaded, this is done by a browser event, however, since mine is a REST call, I can't use the onBrowserEvent() method, and hence, I don't have a handle to the Element, to refresh its information.

I'm thinking maybe I have to do this through table.refresh()? I'd really like the render method to trigger the fetching however.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at the goals of cell widgets, then I don't think this is possible and definitely not desirable :

> Cell widgets (data presentation widgets) are high-performance,
>   lightweight widgets composed of Cells for displaying data.

I have faced a similar problem : suppose you have a Contact with a List of tags but only the tagIds are stored with the contact. To visualize the tags in the table, you would have to make callbacks to the server to get the names.

The solution is in using the adapter pattern. Create a ContactAdapter that holds the contact and the actual tags instead of the tagIds. Pre-fill the contact adapters with the tags based on the tagIds and set the List as the datasource for your celltable.

Comment: I basically did something like this. I created a map and stored the values return from the the REST call as the value. When the column requests the value, if I don't have it in the map, I do the REST call, if I have it, I return it. The Cell just has to know it might get a null value.